# Sobre Date no MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, data

Estou fazendo um programa para um trabalho da faculdade, com conexão ao banco de dados.

Em uma tabela, tenho uma coluna `NASCIMENTO` do tipo `DATE`. No programa tenho um `MaskedTextBox` para inserir a data de nascimento, porém coloquei o nosso meio de datas, `DD/MM/YYYY`, e no banco o padrão é `YYYY/MM/DD`, como converto isso? Pois não estou conseguindo inserir o dado, devido a diferença disso.

Seria melhor converter dentro do `INSERT` da procedure no banco ou fazer pelo C#?

Exemplo: inseri a data 12/04/1992, ela tem que se transformar em 1992/12/04 para ser armazenada no banco.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd

Answer (score 1):

O padrão do MySQL é, `AAAA/MM/DD`, desta forma, o ideal seria você converter no `INSERT` do C#, o que te daria uma portabilidade maior entre os bancos, já que esse padrão é quase para todos os bancos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, você pode converter com o C#

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("04/26/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Recomendo pesquisar melhor suas duvidas antes de perguntar na comunidade, para não ser negativado e ajudar a manter o foco da comunidade em perguntas ainda não sanadas.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839196/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-datetime

Comment: Acabei mudando no banco para string mesmo, vlw ^^

Comment: Trabalhar com Date quando começa a programar pode ser um pouco complicado, mas com o tempo você pega o jeito.
Não desista :P